Use an URL of Wordpress pages in a href of a custom button component (wordpress editor block)
I am creating a button in Wordpress. For this I want to use a custom block editor component
What I want to achieve is a button for which you can select an existing URL based on the pages in your Wordpress installation.
Similar to how the button component of Wordpress itself does it:

When you click on that icon, you will get a prompt to search for a page in Wordpress. When you select a page, the URL of that page will be used as the anchors href.
My own button component
Now I've created my own component. The reason is I want to have some different options for my button.
There is already a link button in the toolbar by default:

That also opens the "Search or type URL" dialogue box nicely.
But what's different than the one on the default button component, is that when you'd select a page, it will here be added the the inner content of the button:

Meaning that it's rendered as this:

Rather than as the href for that element.
How should you fix this?
Should you instead hide the default icon and use your own? What wordpress component could you then use for the "Search or type URL" button?

You can always check how the core/button block implements it. It seems to be using the (experimental) LinkControl component. Alternatively, you could create a variant of the core/button block and add your custom controls to the BlockControls component for that specific variant.

Indeed the LinkControl is what you can do.
The most basic example without 'target' or 'follow' is:
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import {BlockControls, RichText, useBlockProps} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import {
    Popover,
    Toolbar,
    ToolbarButton,
    ToolbarGroup
} from "@wordpress/components";
import { useState, useMemo, useRef } from '@wordpress/element';
import {button, styles as stylesIcon, link } from "@wordpress/icons";
import {buttonFilled, stylesInverted} from "./assets/icons";
import { __experimentalLinkControl as LinkControl } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {

    const richTextRef = useRef();

    const { text, url } = attributes;

    // Use internal state instead of a ref to make sure that the component
    // re-renders when the popover's anchor updates.
    const [isEditingURL, setIsEditingURL] = useState( false );

    const linkValue = useMemo(
        () => ({url}),
        [url]
    );

    function startEditingURL() {
        setIsEditingURL( (state) => !state);
    }

    function unlink() {
        setAttributes({
            url: undefined,
        });
        setIsEditingURL( false );
    }

    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <BlockControls>
                <Toolbar>
                    <ToolbarGroup label="Link">
                        <ToolbarButton icon={ link } label="Link" onClick={startEditingURL} isActive={!!url} />
                    </ToolbarGroup>
                </Toolbar>
            </BlockControls>

            {isEditingURL && (
                <Popover
                    onClose={() => {
                        setIsEditingURL(false);
                        richTextRef.current?.focus();
                    }}
                    // necessary for it to close when you click outside the popover
                    __unstableSlotName="__unstable-block-tools-after"
                >
                    <LinkControl
                        value={linkValue}
                        onChange={(linkValue) => { setAttributes({ url: linkValue.url }); }}
                        onRemove={() => {
                            unlink();
                            richTextRef.current?.focus();
                        }}
                    ></LinkControl>
                </Popover>
            )}

            <RichText
                ref={richTextRef}
                tagName="p"
                className="mb-4"
                value={text}
                onChange={(text) => setAttributes({text})}
                // this will hide the default link button
                allowedFormats={[]}
                placeholder={__('Add text...', 'custom-gutenberg-blocks')}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

